# How a question related to modules connected to Arduino and programmed with ArduinoIDE to achieve a technical spec can be offtopic?

Tags: discussion

I'm doing an Arduino based project but I'm struggling to achieve a long range with RF communication, searching ended up to many questions related to long range communication with a problem analogous to mine but different requirements so I have asked [this question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/90976/how-to-achieve-a-direct-15km-transmission-with-at-least-300kbps-bit-rate)

My question has been instantly downvoted and a bandwagon effect followed and someone blamed the question as offtopic and closed with the motivation that "*same kind of modules could be used also with something different than Arduino, so Arduino is not relevant*".

Maybe it is my opinion that problems like the one of question I have asked, may be useful also to other Arduino users that have to deal with remote controlling and long range communication but sure if applies the rule "*if the modules you are dealing with Arduino could be used regardless Arduino the question should be closed*" an humongous number of questions as a matter of fact should be cleared (basically the most related to modules and sensors without a specific ino code sketch attached) with a negative effect for this stackexchange section.

Certainly I don't

> Feel free to ask about anything related to Arduino.

as stated in guideline.

I frequent many different stackexchange websites related to different tech and science areas and I have the growing impression stackexchange areas related to arduino and electronic seems too much prone to hostile attitude toward questions, and probably is not a coincidence these communities don't grow well as other Stackexchange areas despite the relevance of the respective community topics.

Maybe guidelines that avoid certain ambiguities would either tame "compulsive downvote shooters" or preventing "victims" to waste time asking here.

Comment: You question is not above interacting Arduino with a module. You seek recommendation about long range RF communication technology.

Comment: It was about RF modules to use with arduino not about RF theory. There are many questions of same type as said. What is the difference with this question? https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/44326/very-long-range-wireless-communication-between-two-arduinos500-1000-km or this https://hackaday.com/2014/12/19/gibson-girl-emergency-beacon-built-from-a-wind-up-flashlight/ or https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/67281/increasing-distance-of-ir-remote-transmitter and many many question of this kind  not even mentioning those relates to other kind of tasks?

Comment: questions in the 'gray zone'. the community answers some and closes others.

Answer (score 1):

There is a distinction between "I have this module and I can't get it to work with my Arduino" and "What technology would fulfill these requirements?"

This site is geared towards answering specific technical questions, not discussing the pros and cons of different technologies or products.

Your question amounts to little more than a shopping question (asking for recommendations of products), and as such is for this site. This is not specifically an Arduino policy but a general policy across all (or most) of the technology related exchanges.

In short: if your question is related to Arduino and has a specific "this is what is wrong" answer it is on topic. If an answer is little more than the opinions of people then it really isn't on topic.